# The walk of a knife

Tags: measure-theory, terminology, geometric-measure-theory

"A knife is slowly moved parallel to itself over the top of a cake. At each instant the knife is poised so that it could cut a unique slice of the cake. As time goes by the potential slice increases monotonely from nothing until it becomes the entire cake" ([Dubins & Spanier, "How to cut a cake fairly", 1961](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2311357)).

Define $C$ as the entire cake and define $K_C(t)$ as the subset of $C$ that has already been covered by the knife at time $t$. This function has the following properties:

1. It is a monotonically increasing function of $t$.
2. $K_C(0)=\phi$ and $K_C(T)=C$ (where $T$ is a finite positive number).
3. The Lebesgue measure $L(K_C(t))$ is a continuous increasing function of $t$.
4. For every non-atomic measure $M$ on $C$, the function $M(K_C(t))$ is a continuous non-decreasing function of $t$.

My questions are:

- Is there a formal term for a function $K_C(t)$ having all these properties?
- Does such a function exist for every "cake" (set) $C$? If not, under what conditions it is possible to define a function $K_C(t)$ over a set given $C$?
- Is property 4 required in the definition of $K_C(t)$, or can it be inferred from the previous properties? (I ask this question because I would like to have a simpler definition of the "knife walk", without using "for every non-atomic measure").

Comment: What would "continuity of $K_C$" mean?

Comment: @LuizCordeiro you are right... it is not clear. Maybe continuity should be defined based on a pre-specified measure. I made an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual setting for this procedure is that $C$ is a set with positive, but finite, Lebesgue measure. Now $4$ holds for measures absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measures but not with respect to every nonatomic measure.

Suppose you move the knife in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the blade parallel to the vertical axis. The measure that is uniformly distributed over the line segment $\{0\}\times [0,1]$ will lead to a jump in measure once the knife has reached the horizontal axis.

The implicit formalization of a moving knife is that you take a linear functional $l$ on some $\mathbb{R}^n$ and look at the measure $\mu$ of the intersection of $C$ with the halfspaces $H_t=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:l(x)\leq t\}$. So $K_C(t):\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is given by

$$K_t(C)=\mu(C\cap H_t).$$

The counterexample given is essentially Example $1$ of

> Hill, Theodore P., and Kent E. Morrison. "[Cutting cakes
>   carefully.](http://digitalcommons.calpoly.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1075&context=rgp_rsr)" The College Mathematics Journal 41.4 (2010): 281-288.

The paper has an [interesting history](http://de.scribd.com/doc/19819297/How-to-Publish-Counterexamples-in-1-2-3-Easy-Steps), that might tell you more about the field than you might want to know.

Comment: So, for every linear functional I get a function $K_C(t)$ with the above 4 properties? Doesn't it have to be continuous?

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi I think the definition of the knife cutting procedure is faily canonical. For measures absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure, the function $K_C$ will be continuous. Otherwise, the counterexample I gave applies.

Comment: What I meant to ask is: you say that the function $K_C$ can be defined using a linear functional $l$. So, can I take *any* linear functional $l$ and get a function $K_C$ that is continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure? Or, are there some constraints on the possible linear functional, i.e. the linear functional itself must be continuous?

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi You can choose every nontrivial (that is nonzero) functional on $\mathbb{R}^n$. There are no discontinuous linear functionals on $\mathbb{R}^n$.